# Error Jenkins to execute ansible-playbook

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying execute a Jenkins Pipeline that runs a simple ansible playbook.

Ansible is installled and configured on Global Tool Configuration.

[Ansible --version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixMyT.png)

[Global Tool Configuration Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3psZ.png)

["PATH" Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL85h.png)

Jenkins Pipeline:

[Pipeline calling playbook function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nnwh1.png)

I get the following message when try execute the pipeline.

```
[pipeline-maven-project] $ docker exec --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** 5c3dd29434b00c89b12637ee632e805b1987bd8934f6d9d95f4d90b755834237 ansible-playbook /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipeline-maven-project/playbook.yml
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"ansible-playbook\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
FATAL: command execution failed
hudson.AbortException: Ansible playbook execution failed
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.perform(AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.java:262)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.workflow.AnsiblePlaybookStep$AnsiblePlaybookExecution.run(AnsiblePlaybookStep.java:430)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.workflow.AnsiblePlaybookStep$AnsiblePlaybookExecution.run(AnsiblePlaybookStep.java:351)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:367)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Ansible playbook execution failed
```

Comment: Does the `ansible --version` was executed in image `5c3dd29434b00c89b12637ee632e805b1987bd8934f6d9d95f4d90b755834237`, which is the image jenkins is using to execute the step? (Please paste text directly instead of screenshot of text, it's easier to read)

Comment: Please do not provide code, logs, output, error messages... in images: in most cases it is barely readable, it impairs search engines ability to index the content, it prevents people trying to help you to copy/paste content if needed, it uses (in best cases...) 1000 times more data volume (e.g. disk space to store, data transfers....) than the equivalent text in code/citation block... and above all, it is specifically listed as a bad practice in [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks